# How to save two files in R?

Tags: output, r

I need to save data automatically to avoid naming mistakes later, but I would like to have a duplicate copy in `Rplots.pdf`. 
Code to have one file, but not sure how to use it for two output files

```
data <- "sinus"
filename <- paste("Rplots.", data, ".pdf")
pdf(filename, height=10, width=10)
```

I need it because I like to do `Rscript code.r && evince Rplots.pdf`.

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an R programming question not related to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking, too (so I might be wrong about that). I think this would be on-topic at [so], but a clearer problem statement would be necessary.

Comment: Ideally you'd also say what you'd tried already.

Comment: @MichaelHomer See OttoV's comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

Why not copy the file to the new file name using file.copy()

From the R manual:

```
file.copy(from, to, overwrite = recursive, recursive = FALSE,
      copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can this be done during the same script which does `Rplots.special.pdf`? Do `from` and `to` have to be absolute PATHs?

Comment: You can add the file.copy() operation within your script, immediately after the pdf() line. from and to do not have to be absolute PATHs but using absolute paths can help locating files if things go wrong.

Comment: Another option is to add the cp command to your command-line: `Rscript code.r && cp -f Rplots.pdf myCopy.pdf && evince Rplots.pdf`

Comment: The last one will not work because I put the practice in place because I have had problems in using generic names too much. There is too much human error me typing precisely names, so it cannot be an option.